# more then one Values in one Parameter from $_get

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I have a html form, where more than one values are submitted by one parameter.
How can I handle it in php

The whole thing looks like this:

Single parameter:
shoppingcart = Item 1 
shoppingcart = Item 2 
shoppingcart = Item 3 
shoppingcart = Item 3 
Name = Max 
Surname = Brown 
Adress = New York

Comment: Please post HTML form..

Comment: You can use `shoppingcart[]` for fields and you'll get array of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you have to assign name a array like**

```
<input type="text" name="shoppingcart[]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you get  submit an array  you should use it as an array   eg:

```
$my_item_array  = $_GET['shoppingcart '];


foreach($my_item_array as $key => $value){

 echo $value . <br />;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Parameter as array type in html form `shoppingcart[]` and  you can hanle it php loop.

```
foreach($_GET['shoppingcart'] as $item){
        echo $item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this,

form,

```html
item1: <input type="text" name="shoppingcart[]"/>
item2: <input type="text" name="shoppingcart[]"/>
```

Then in your php code,

```
$items = $_GET["shoppingcart"];
```

Answer (score 0):

$_GET is supper global varieble in php. It's array and you can use it in following form:

Imagine to have following html form:

```
<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and welcome_get.php look like this:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
```